# In python, my input prompt is printing a second time after I answer it once

Tags: python, function, if-statement, logic

In my text-adventure game, when I have

*Would You like To Play (yes/no)yes

Ah! You are being chased by something! You need to go fast!

Should you take the bike or the skateboard (bike/skateboard)skateboard

Ah! You are being chased by something! You need to go fast!

Should you take the bike or the skateboard (bike/skateboard)*

This means when I choose skateboard once, the question repeats, but if I chose bike, it goes on normally. This is the code:

```
def chooseAnswer():
    answer=''
    while answer.lower().strip() !='yes' and answer.lower().strip() !='no':
        answer = input('Would You like To Play (yes/no)')
    return answer
def chooseAnswer1():
    answer1=''
    while answer1.lower().strip() !='bike' and answer1.lower().strip() !='skateboard':
        answer1= input('''Ah! You are being chased by something! You need to go fast!\nShould you take the bike or the skateboard (bike/skateboard)''')

    return answer1
#Branches off 1 if choose Bike
def chooseAnswer11():
    answer11=''
    while answer11.lower().strip() !='right' and answer11.lower().strip() != 'left':
        answer11= input('''You see two paths. Quickly, you have to decide which path to go on! The left one is dark and looks like it goes down a cave. The right one goes up a hill and into sunlight.(left/right)''')
 return answer11
#Branches Off 1 if choose skateboard
def chooseAnswer12():
    answer12=''
    while answer12.lower().strip() !='sleep' and answer12.lower().strip() != 'awake':
        answer12= input('''Quickly you hop on your skateboard, heading for woods.\nYou settle for the night in the woods.\nYou see the mysterious thing that is search for you.\nDo you sleep or stay awake?(awake/sleep)''')

    return answer12

if chooseAnswer()=='yes':
    if chooseAnswer1()=='bike':
        if chooseAnswer11()=='right':
            if chooseAnswer111()=='TBD':
                print('TBD')
            elif chooseAnswer112()=='TBD':
                print('TBD')
        elif chooseAnswer11=='left':
            if chooseAnswer121()=='TBD':
                print('TBD')
            elif chooseAnswer122()=='TBD':
                print('TBD')
    elif chooseAnswer1()=='skateboard':
        if chooseAnswer12()=='awake':
```

Anyone see why the input prompt is repeating twice?

Comment: Your example code isn't complete. At the very least, we would like to see the definitions of your chooseAnswer* functions.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read and therefore to maintain. I suggest you write a framework to read user inputs have a general method to handle input

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being caused by calling the `chooseAnswer1` function in your conditionals.

```
if chooseAnswer()=='yes':
    # First call of chooseAnswer1
    if chooseAnswer1()=='bike':

        ...Code Removed for Readability...

    # second call of chooseAnswer1 
    elif chooseAnswer1()=='skateboard':
        if chooseAnswer12()=='awake':
```

To fix this you'll want to assign the function call to a variable and then compare the object it returns to that variable in your conditional. You'll likely want to do this for all functions throughout your program:

```
# Single call of chooseAnswer
answer0 = chooseAnswer()
if answer0 == 'yes':
    # Single call of chooseAnswer1
    answer1 = chooseAnswer1()
    if answer1 == 'bike':

        ...Code Removed for Readability...

    # Since the variable is assigned to the returned object,
    # the function is not called again in the elif condition.
    elif answer1 == 'skateboard':
        answer12 = chooseAnswer12()
        if answer12 == 'awake':
```

Also Python 3.8's new walrus `:=` operator may also be useful here, but I'm still using 3.7 so I'm going to leave it to someone else to provide code examples on how to use it in this situation.

Edit: OP said in a comment to my answer:

> So I ran into another problem with this. I assigned all the functions variables, so when I think it goes in order I put the variables in. What I'm saying is when the first question pops up, it answers it as though I said yes and even though I say skateboard, it gives me the bike path.

My response is too long to post into a comment due to how long the url is for this [python tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20chooseAnswer%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20answer%20%3D%20''%0A%20%20%20%20while%20answer.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'yes'%20and%20answer.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'no'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer%20%3D%20input%28'Would%20You%20like%20To%20Play%20%28yes/no%29'%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20answer%0A%0A%0Adef%20chooseAnswer1%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20answer1%20%3D%20''%0A%20%20%20%20while%20answer1.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'bike'%20and%20answer1.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'skateboard'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer1%20%3D%20input%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'''Ah!%20You%20are%20being%20chased%20by%20something!%20You%20need%20to%20go%20fast!%5CnShould%20you%20take%20the%20bike%20or%20the%20skateboard%20%28bike/skateboard%29'''%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20answer1%0A%0A%0Adef%20chooseAnswer11%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20answer11%20%3D%20''%0A%20%20%20%20while%20answer11.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'right'%20and%20answer11.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'left'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer11%20%3D%20input%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'''You%20see%20two%20paths.%20Quickly,%20you%20have%20to%20decide%20which%20path%20to%20go%20on!%20The%20left%20one%20is%20dark%20and%20looks%20like%20it%20goes%20down%20a%20cave.%20The%20right%20one%20goes%20up%20a%20hill%20and%20into%20sunlight.%28left/right%29'''%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20answer11%0A%0A%0Adef%20chooseAnswer12%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20answer12%20%3D%20''%0A%20%20%20%20while%20answer12.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'sleep'%20and%20answer12.lower%28%29.strip%28%29%20!%3D%20'awake'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer12%20%3D%20input%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'''Quickly%20you%20hop%20on%20your%20skateboard,%20heading%20for%20woods.%5CnYou%20settle%20for%20the%20night%20in%20the%20woods.%5CnYou%20see%20the%20mysterious%20thing%20that%20is%20search%20for%20you.%5CnDo%20you%20sleep%20or%20stay%20awake%3F%28awake/sleep%29'''%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20answer12%0A%0A%0Aanswer0%20%3D%20chooseAnswer%28%29%0Aif%20answer0%20%3D%3D%20'yes'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20answer1%20%3D%20chooseAnswer1%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20if%20answer1%20%3D%3D%20'bike'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer11%20%3D%20chooseAnswer11%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20answer11%20%3D%3D%20'right'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%22right%20path%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20answer11%20%3D%3D%20'left'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%22left%20path%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20answer1%20%3D%3D%20'skateboard'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer12%20%3D%20chooseAnswer12%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20answer12%20%3D%3D%20'sleep'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%22sleep%20path%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20answer12%20%3D%3D%20'awake'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%22awake%20path%22%29%0A&cumulative=true&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), but I recommend they compare their placement of their function calls to where I placed them in my example:

```
answer0 = chooseAnswer()
if answer0 == 'yes':
    answer1 = chooseAnswer1()
    if answer1 == 'bike':
        answer11 = chooseAnswer11()
        if answer11 == 'right':
            print("right path")
        elif answer11 == 'left':
            print("left path")
    elif answer1 == 'skateboard':
        answer12 = chooseAnswer12()
        if answer12 == 'sleep':
            print("sleep path")
        elif answer12 == 'awake':
            print("awake path")
```

The key detail here is placement of the function calls.